# Как правильно вытащить данные с class без span внутри него?

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вытащить данные из следующего кода?

```html
<div class="day">
  <a href="/prognoz/semipalatinsk/14dney/#day2" class="day__link" name="clb3279967">
    <div class="day__date">Завтра</div>
    <div class="weather-icon weather-icon_05 margin-bottom-10" title="переменная облачность"></div>
    <div class="day__temperature" title="Днем">+9&deg;
      <span class="day__temperature__night" title="Ночью">0&deg;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="day__description"
```

Парсер на Питоне такой

```
import requests, bs4
s=requests.get('https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/semipalatinsk/')
b=bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")
p3=b.select('.day__date')
pogoda1=p3[0].getText()
p4=b.select('.day .day__temperature')
pogoda2=p4[0].getText()
p5=b.select('.day__temperature__night')
pogoda3=p5[0].getText()
p6=b.select('.day__description')
pogoda4=p6[0].getText()
print(pogoda1 + ' ' + pogoda2 + ' ' + pogoda3 + ' ' + pogoda4)
```

Вывод  кода

```
> Завтра +9°
> 0° 
> 0° облачно``
```

А нужно чтобы было так

```
> Завтра +9° 0° облачно
```

Понимаю, что проблема возникает из-за спана внутри класса `day__temperature`. Но как его отбросить не понятно.

Comment: 1- вы просто лишний пробел хотите убрать? Попробуйте strip=True в get_text() передать. Или вы не хотите весь текст из `div.day__temperature` забирать? (тогда к примеру, strip_strings атрибут можно использовать 2- вы можете select_one() использовать 3- requests может неправильную кодировку использовать (`s.text`). Лучшее на beautifulsoup полагаться, чтобы кодировку в html найти 4- вместо поиска в html, который может легко поменяться, посмотрите есть ли явное API у сайта (или его источников, аналогов), которое нужную информацию позволяет достать

Comment: Там после +9 присутствуют множество табов затем 0.  Кстати табы не отобразились. Я думаю что, тут два варианта: либо  убрать табы и тогда следующий day__temperature__night будет не нужен. Либо обрезать day__temperature до 4х символов. И "0" вытаскивать из day__temperature__night. Думаю делать это нужно через getText, а не item.find т.к. в последнем случае находит только первое совпадение.

Comment: `find()` работает абсолютно точно как он должен работать и возвращает именно тот результат, который в ответе показан. Вы определитесь, что вы точно хотите получить в итоге и обновите вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
        Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
    }

 url = 'https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/semipalatinsk/'

 page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content

 item = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

 presently = item.find('a', {'href': '/prognoz/semipalatinsk/14dney/#day2'}).text

 tomorrow = item.find('a', {'href': '/prognoz/semipalatinsk/14dney/#day3'}).text

 print(presently.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ''))

 print(tomorrow.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так решить проблему

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
            Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
        }

url = 'https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/semipalatinsk/'

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content

item = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

date = item.find('div', {'class': 'day__date'}).text

day_temperature = item.find('div', {'class': 'day__temperature'}).text

day_temperature_night = item.find('span', {'class': 'day__temperature__night'}).text

day__description = item.find('div', {'class': 'day__description'}).text

print(date, day_temperature[0:4], day_temperature_night, day__description)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Но find насколько я понимаю находит первое совпадение. А мне нужно кроме погоды на завтра еще и послезавтра и т.д. парсить. Извините, забыл упомянуть об этом т.к. в момент когда задавал вопрос был сосредоточен исключительно на первой строке ("Завтра").

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы первую непустую строку напечатать из `div.day__temperature` элемента:

```
print(next(soup.find('div', 'day__temperature').stripped_strings))
```

или

```
print(next(soup.select_one('div.day__temperature').stripped_strings))
```

Результат в обоих случаях: `+9°`.